# VBScript "GenerateXSD" command creates empty "include" elements

Tags: xsd, enterprise-architect

Is there a way to use VBScript or JScript in Enterprise Architect to correctly generate "include" elements?  It seems there are no options analogous to the "Use relative-path to reference XSDs" option that is present in the "Generate XML Schema" GUI.  Hence, "include" elements are empty.

I have two packages:

1. "Primitives", which contains a custom "BinaryContent" class
2. "Event", which contains an "Event" class, which has an element of type "BinaryContent".  So "Event" references "Primitives".

Using the "Generate XML Schema" GUI and ticking the "Use relative-path to reference XSDs" option, Event.xsd generates fine:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:include schemaLocation="Primitives.xsd"/>
    <xs:complexType name="Event">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="list" type="BinaryContent" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="100"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

But the VBScript `GenerateXSD` command:

`project.GenerateXSD currentPackage.PackageGUID, "D:/EA_Test/schema/" + currentPackage.Name + ".xsd", "UTF-8", ""`

generates an empty "include" element:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:include/>
    <xs:complexType name="Event">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="list" type="BinaryContent" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="100"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

According to the [Enterprise Architect documentation](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.3/automation/project_2.html), the only option supported on the GenerateXSD command that would go in the empty quotes above is `GenGlobalElement`, which is not the option I want.  What am I missing?